# How to ask user to enter another value until user enters only positive number in plsql

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findSquareRoot 
 ( v_num in NUMBER)
  is negative_Number Exception; 
BEGIN
    if(v_num<0) then
        RAISE negative_Number;
    else
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Square root of '||v_num||' is'||SQRT(v_num));
    end if;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN negative_Number THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20989,'Please provide a valid number');
END;
```

---

Test Block using loop

```
DECLARE
  lv_input  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   LOOP
       lv_input := &num
       findSquareRoot(lv_input);
       EXIT WHEN lv_input > 0;
   END LOOP;
end;
```

Even though I'm mentioning it should exit only when input is greater than zero, Loop is getting executed only once.

Comment: No. That's not possible, you can't run interactive programs in PL/SQL like this. It can take input only once per execution of script, that's all. You may use a shell script to do what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

in your logic-there is no return value from your `procedure` `findSquareRoot` 
it is ended up with an exception;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findSquareRoot 
 ( v_num in out NUMBER)

    BEGIN
        if(v_num<0) then
            v_num:=0;
        else
            v_num:=1;
        end if;
    EXCEPTION
     WHEN others THEN
          dbms_outout.put_line(sqlcode);
    END;
```

Comment: As per requirement i should throw an exception if user entered number is less than 0 and prompt the user to provide another value

Answer (score 0):

As you were told, PL/SQL can't help here.

If you're on MS Windows, you might do it with a simple batch script. Here's how.

- batch script will ask user to enter a value, and will continue doing that until the positive number is entered
- once the above condition is met, it runs SQL*Plus and calls the .SQL script which runs the procedure, passing the parameter user has entered

Here are the scripts:

**SQROOT.BAT**

```
@echo off
:repeat
set /p numb="Enter a positive number : "
if %numb% lss 0 goto :repeat
sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl @sqroot %numb%
```

**SQROOT.SQL**

```
set serveroutput on
exec findSquareRoot(&1)
```

**Your procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findsquareroot (v_num IN NUMBER)
IS
   negative_number   EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   IF (v_num < 0)
   THEN
      RAISE negative_number;
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'Square root of ' || v_num || ' is ' || SQRT (v_num));
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN negative_number
   THEN
      raise_application_error (-20989, 'Please provide a valid number');
END;
/
```

---

**Testing:**

```
M:\>sqroot
Enter a positive number : -2
Enter a positive number : 25

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Pon Lip 11 08:35:47 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Square root of 25 is 5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

This isn't *perfect* and could/should be improved, but - for a quick note, I hope you got the idea.